# Google Calendar API. Patching sharedExtendedProperty for events

Tags: calendar, patch, google-calendar-api

I have created event in my Google calendar. Most interesting part is:

```
{
// some event data;
 "extendedProperties": {
  "shared": {
   "cases_1": "1",
   "cases_2": "2"
  }
 }
}
```

Right now I need to PATCH existing event. In `extendedProperties` I do not need `"cases_1":"1"` any more. So I use [developers endpoint](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch) to patch it. The PATCH request body is:

```
{
 "extendedProperties": {
  "shared": {
   "cases_2": "2"
  }
 }
}
```

In response I see my both shared fields. How must my request body look like to remove from `extendedProperties` shared `cases_1` field?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the line below to your request:

```
{
 "extendedProperties": {
  "shared": {
   "cases_1": null,
   "cases_2": "2"
  }
 }
}
```

It was shown in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/extended-properties#deleting):

> Any properties not included in an update request will be deleted, but
>    a better approach is to make a patch request to set the value to null

Hope this helps.